# Contact Diary Desktop Application

Tags: windows, gratis

As one of the measures to curb the spread of covid-19, it is recommended (at least in Germany) to keep a "contact diary". That would be a list of people you have come in closer contact during the day for more than a brief moment, along with notes whether e.g. some or all people involved were wearing masks, whether the encounter happened in an enclosed space, etc.

**I am looking for a Windows desktop application that easily lets me keep a contact diary.**

There are various mobile apps, but I do not like the prospect of typing even more on that tiny on-screen keyboard.

Open source is preferred, but not a must; however, the application should be usable free of charge.

Comment: A quick query to the bingleduck didn't find any - but it seems to me that you could easily manage this with just notepad, the old Windows Cardfile, a spreadsheet, or any app that lets you set up fields that allow free-form text.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I surely could, but who doesn't like a specialized tool that saves a couple of clicks.

Comment: @F-H - you can use any desktop version of Windows Outlook for this. If not, you can use MyPhoneExplorer which has a desktop contact manager (even if you don't want to sync with Android phone). I can enter full answer if interested. Both have a "Notes" field at contact level